Pymodbus: ModbusSlaveContext.setValues() missing 1 required positional
Estoy tratando de diseñar un servidor Modbus TCP/IP a traves de python utilizando la libreria Pymodbus. Este es el codigo:
from pymodbus.server.sync import ModbusTcpServer
from pymodbus.datastore import ModbusSlaveContext, ModbusServerContext
from pymodbus.transaction import ModbusRtuFramer
import threading
import time


rtu_client = ModbusRTUClient(method='rtu', port='COM1', baudrate=9600, timeout=1000)
store = ModbusSlaveContext(
    di=None,  # Deshabilitar entradas discretas
    co=None,  # Deshabilitar coils
    hr=ModbusSlaveContext(),  # Habilitar holding registers
    ir=None   # Deshabilitar input registers
)
context = ModbusServerContext(slaves=store, single=True)

# Función para actualizar los holding registers desde RTU
def update_context():
    while True:
        try:
            if rtu_client.connect():
                result = rtu_client.read_holding_registers(address=0x00, count=10, unit=1)
                rtu_client.close()
                if not result.isError() and result.registers is not None:
                    print("Valores a establecer:", result.registers)
                    context[0].setValues(3, 0x00, result.registers)
                else:
                    print("No se pudieron obtener los registros o los registros son inválidos")
            else:
                print("Fallo en la conexión con el dispositivo RTU.")
        except TypeError as e:
            print(f"Error en setValues: {str(e)}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error inesperado: {str(e)}")
        time.sleep(1)  # Intervalo entre lecturas

# Ejecutar actualización en un hilo separado
thread = threading.Thread(target=update_context)
thread.start()

# Configuración e inicio del servidor TCP
server = ModbusTcpServer(context, address=("192.168.1.36", 502))
server.serve_forever()

Pero al ejecutarlo, en la linea de comando, obtengo lo siguiente:
Valores a establecer: [3645, 3645, 3645, 3645, 3645, 3645, 3645, 3645, 3645, 3645] Error en setValues: ModbusSlaveContext.setValues() missing 1 required positional argument:values
Si bien leo los primeros 10 registros, tengo el error que sigue y no logro descifrarlo. Necesito ayuda urgente por favor. No entiendo cual es el error que estoy cometiendo.
